# How to sort random floating numbers?

Tags: python

Hi I am struggling with something fairly simple. 
I just want to generate a specific series of random floating numbers and sort them from lowest to highest.
This is how I started,

```
from random import *
#import random
import random

for i in xrange(5):
    list= '%2.3f' % random.uniform(0,10)
    print list
```

This code snippet gives me 5 random floating numbers, but I dont know how to sort them.

Comment: Best approach here is to store them in a `list` and then sort the list. and never use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: You're not putting your numbers in a list. You're just assigning them to a badly named variable called `list`.

Comment: you need to create an empty list like this list = [] and then append it with your numbers. That should be your starting point

Answer (score 2):

You should create an empty *list* and then append the items to it. Then, you can use the built-in `sorted` function to print get the sorted array.

```
import random

my_list =  []
for i in xrange(5):
    my_list.append( '%2.3f' % random.uniform(0,10))
```

Now if you print the list you'll get:

```
>>> print my_list
['6.482', '7.542', '8.361', '4.703', '1.174']
```

And this is how you sort it:

```
>>> print sorted(my_list)
['1.174', '4.703', '6.482', '7.542', '8.361']
```

If you want to permanently sort the list use `my_list.sort()`:

```
>>> my_list.sort()
>>> print my_list
['1.174', '4.703', '6.482', '7.542', '8.361']
```

I suggest you not to use "list" as a variable name, it is a really bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints five random numbers, but you are not storing them in a `list`.

Here’s one way of doing it. I'm using Python 3.6.1

```
import random

random_floats = ['{:2.3f}'.format(random.uniform(0, 10)) for _ in range(5)]
print(sorted(random_floats))
```

Printing the list elements after `sorting` them. The random values are in the `(0, 10)` range:

```
['0.923', '1.004', '2.119', '7.192', '9.477']
```

Like others have already suggested, avoid using `list` as a variable name.

**Edit**: It’s a Python convention to use `_` as a throwaway variable.